# Can I specify in a SQLite query that a column have ANY value?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to design a feature where the user can specify what data they get back from a query. Below are the search options to the end user.

- Players with a contract (non-null contractId)
- Players without a contract (null contractId)
- All Players (null or non-null contractId)

I'd like to make a function that can take a String and plug it into a query to return the desired data set.

```
public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers(String contractFilter) {
    String query = "... WHERE player.ContractId is " + contractFilter;
}
```

With this design, I can pass in `contractFilter = "null"` or `contractFilter = "not null"`.  **Is there something I can pass in for the 3rd condition (null OR non-null)? Something like `contractFilter = "any"`**?

Comment: I think `not null` represent `any`

Comment: @MD by "any", I mean I want to return either `null` or `not null`. I've updated my question to clarify that point.

Comment: Do not include that column in the `WHERE` clause. Only include columns for which you specifically want to constrain the result.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I know I could simply not filter by that column. My question is more about whether syntax exists that allows me to specify an "any" filter for the column. If not, I can of course add more logic to alter the query in the 3rd case.

Comment: "My question is more about whether syntax exists that allows me to specify an "any" filter for the column" -- you could try using `columname IS NULL OR columnname IS NOT NULL`. Unless SQLite specifically detects this and converts all that into a no-op, though, I would expect it to perform worse than simply not including the column at all in your query. Similarly, since SQLite is only loosely typed, you could try something like `LIKE '%'`, though once again performance may suffer.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thank you! That is the kind of answer and explanation was what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer, I would gladly accept it. Cheers.

Comment: make a one more string field in your table , insert Players with a contract as a 1,Players without a contract as a 2, All Players as a 3 Query the table field where you get 1 it is Players with a contract and where you get 2 Players without a contract. you can apply this idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the best solution is to simply not include the column in your `WHERE` clause. If you use something [like `SQLiteQueryBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html), just skip that `appendWhere()` call when the condition is "any".

You can try to hack around this:

- Use `column_name IS NULL OR column_name IS NOT NULL`
- Use `column_name LIKE '%'`

However, there is a decent chance that these will perform worse. Ideally, SQLite's query planner will detect the "any" case and optimize it away, but I would not assume that to be the case.